# How to get values from DataTable to combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable

I write winform the application in C#. It has a problem when using combobox with `DataTable`.
I have `DataTable` like:

```
**privilege**       **username**       **password**

  admin                admin               8887abc

  user                 user1               abc123
```

And I load it to `combobox`. Only show privilege column, when the user clicks to admin or user, it auto load **username** and **password** corresponding with rows user click to `Textbox` user and password. I can't get the event when User click chose the privilege.

My code like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "privilege";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbCategory.DataSource = dt;

foreach(DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
{
    txtUser.Text = rows["username"].ToString();
    txtPassword.Text = rows["password"].ToString();
}

cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I load DataTable from excel file.
This only all my code. 1 class to read data in Excel, load Excel data from path to DataTable.

Comment: You need to provide full code-behind with class/method names, one can not know what kind of application is this, desktop? web?

Comment: I'm using winform to development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind a handler to cmbCategory.SelectedIndexChanged like so:

```
cmbCategory.SelectedIndexChanged += cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

then define a method

```
void cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get the selection
   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)cmbCategory.SelectedItem;

   // and display the info
   txtUser.Text = drv["username"].ToString();
   txtPassword.Text = drv["password"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why you get an array if there will be only one item that matches the search?

Comment: I have many rows. I think must using foreach to loop all rows in `dt`. Do you think like this?

Comment: I made an edit. I was mixed up between windows ComboBox and web forms DropDownList. The SelectedItem will be the whole DataRow (or DataRowView) so you have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

The combobox control has an event named "SelectedIndexChanged" it's just needed to handle that event, so when the item changed you can either look for the specific item in the DataTable or get the selected item of the combo (it will also be an instance of the datatable item) and then you search the values of the columns you want.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly DataTable MyData = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Assign the event handler
            comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var column1 = new DataColumn("privilege", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            var column2 = new DataColumn("username", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            var column3 = new DataColumn("password", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            MyData.Columns.Add(column1);
            MyData.Columns.Add(column2);
            MyData.Columns.Add(column3);

            var row0 = MyData.NewRow();
            row0["privilege"] = "Select an Item";
            row0["username"] = "";
            row0["password"] = "";

            var row1 = MyData.NewRow();
            row1["privilege"] = "admin";
            row1["username"] = "admin";
            row1["password"] = "8887abc";

            var row2 = MyData.NewRow();
            row2["privilege"] = "user";
            row2["username"] = "user1";
            row2["password"] = "abc123";

            MyData.Rows.Add(row0);
            MyData.Rows.Add(row1);
            MyData.Rows.Add(row2);

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "privilege";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "username";
            comboBox1.DataSource = MyData;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var cb = (sender as ComboBox);

                var selectedItem = (cb.SelectedItem as DataRowView);

                label1.Text = selectedItem["username"].ToString();
                label2.Text = selectedItem["password"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```